# Unable to draw multiple instace of same Image with GraphicsContext

Tags: scala, scalafx

Hi guys this is my first question, so feel free to give constructive criticism.
I am making a space shooter game with ScalaFX and I'm facing a problem where when I am drawing the bullet `laser` in my `AnimationTimer` loop, whenever the player shoots another bullet, the program only renders the newest bullet and the old bullet just disappears.

For the sake of brevity, I'm going to post the main `AnimationTimer` loop related to the bullet input and rendering only:

```
      //List of stuffs (Bullets, enemies etc)
      var laserListB : ListBuffer[Laser] = ListBuffer()

      val timer = AnimationTimer( currentNanoTime => {
      //Calculating time since last frame for frame independant rendering
      var elapsedTime : Double = (currentNanoTime - lastNanoTime) / 1000000000.0;
      lastNanoTime = currentNanoTime;

      //Input check
      //SKIPPED PLAYER MOVEMENT CODE
      if(shootPress){
        var now = System.nanoTime()
        //Checking for atkSpeed cooldwon
        if((lastShootNano <= 0L) || ((now - lastShootNano) >= player.atkSpeed)){
          laserListB += player.shoot()
        }
        lastShootNano = now
      }
      
      //Updating position
      for(laser <- laserListB){
        laser.sprite.velocityX = 0
        laser.sprite.velocityY = -400
        laser.sprite.update(elapsedTime)
      }

      //Rendering
      //Bullets
      for(laser <- laserListB){
        laser.sprite.render(gc)
      }
      
    })
```

And the following is my `Sprite` class:

```
import scalafx.scene.image.Image
import scalafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext
import scalafx.geometry.Rectangle2D

class Sprite(
    private var _image : Image,
    private var _positionX : Double,
    private var _positionY : Double,
    private var _velocityX : Double,
    private var _velocityY : Double,
    private var _width : Double,
    private var _height : Double){

    //Functions
    def render(gc : GraphicsContext){
        gc.drawImage(_image, _positionX, _positionY);
    }
}
```

And if you need, here's my player's shoot function:

```
    def shoot() = {
        //Setting up laser sprite
        val laser = new Laser(_atkSprite, damage, true)
        laser.sprite.velocityX = 0 
        laser.sprite.velocityY = -400 
        laser.sprite.positionX = _sprite.positionX + (_sprite.width / 2)       //Center laser horizontally on player sprite
        laser.sprite.positionY = _sprite.positionY - 10                   //Slight offset to be a bit higher than the player sprite
        laser
    }
```

Thank you for reading this far :D

Edit 1:
Here's a video demonstrating the problem: https://youtu.be/DliNyBoa1DI

Comment: This is too much code and too many questions. Try to cut this down to the smallest example that shows the problem, and ask just one question. And I strongly recommend that you avoid `var` and make `Sprite` immutable, as I suspect that is where the problem is.

Comment: Ok then, I will edit the question to reflect the title. As for Sprite, I'll try to change it to `val` and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it, it wasn't a problem with GraphicsContext but rather due to the fact, `Laser` is instantiated with the same `Sprite` in player.shoot(), therefore all `Laser`s will have the same X and Y, and be overlapped, thus appearing as if it "disappeared".

The new code instantiates a new `Sprite` everytime `Laser` is instantiated as follows:

```
    def shoot() = {
        //Laser sprites
        val atkImg = new Image(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/Images/small_laser_blue.png"))
        val atkSprite = new Sprite(atkImg, 0, 0, 0, 0, atkImg.getWidth(), atkImg.getHeight())
        val laser_ = new Laser(atkSprite, _damage, true)
        laser_.sprite.velocityX = 0 
        laser_.sprite.velocityY = -400 
        laser_.sprite.positionX = _sprite.positionX + (_sprite.width / 2)  //Center laser horizontally on player sprite
        laser_.sprite.positionY = _sprite.positionY - 10                   //Slight offset to be a bit higher than the player sprite
    }
```